# 並列パターンライブラリ（PPL)を用いたDLLをC#から使う

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

表題の通り、並列パターンライブラリ（PPL)を使用しているDLLをC#側から利用しようと思い、
C++/CLIでラッパーDLLを作成していたのですが、

**ERROR: Concurrency Runtime is not supported when compiling /clr.**
とエラーが発生しました。
どうもPPLはCLI上からは使えないようなのですが、
このライブラリをどうにかC#上から使う方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

エラーメッセージにある通り、C++/CLIとPPLは併用不可能です。以下の代案が考えられます。

1. [System.Threading.Tasks 名前空間](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx) 以下のクラスを用いて、C#で並列処理を書き直す。PPL相当の機能が提供されます。
2. C++/CLIではなくネイティブC++でラッパーDLLを作る。C#からはP/InvokeでDLL関数を呼び出す。
3. [本家SO質問の回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3948016/684921)によれば、C++ソースを分離してPimplイディオムで行ける？（Body側は/clr無し、Handle側は有りでコンパイルしてリンク可能？）

Comment: 結局、ネイティブのDLLを作成し、C#側からはDLLImportを用いました。